# FFMPEG - avformat_open_input() always return error with flv file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

```
const char* filename = "D:\\abc.flv";
err = avformat_open_input(&ic, filename, NULL, 0);
```

This function always returns error when filename is `*.flv`. 
If I use file mp4 `(*.mp4)`, it's ok.

Please help me find the cause of this problem!!

Comment: What build (dll/so/lib) of mmpeg are you using, did you compile it yourself? It is possible that it's compiled without flv demuxer. Also what is the error code?

Comment: Thank you so much, Anton!
After setting flv demuxer on config.h from 0 to 1, It runs well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable flx demuxer on configure phase by

```
configure --enable-demuxer=flv [rest of your configurations]
```

This is the same as you change flv demuxer from config.h, but changing the value directly will skip feature validation process, which might not be very safe under certain circumstances. So it's best to enable the demuxer on configure stage to ensure it works.

Comment: Thank you so much Jason,
Your suggestion is valuable to me.